# How to use the foreign key in condition html Django

Tags: python, html, django, list, django-class-based-views

Anyone know why this condition doesn't work? In the h4 the lancamento.tipo shows the information "Receita", but the condition does not work. Please help me on this.

lancamento_list.html

```
    <div class="list-group">
    {% for lancamento in object_list %}
        {% if lancamento.tipo == 'Receita' %}
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{lancamento.tipo}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Descrição: {{lancamento.descricao}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Valor: R$ {{lancamento.valor}}</p>
    </a>
        {% else %}
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{lancamento.tipo}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Descrição: {{lancamento.descricao}}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Valor: R$ {{lancamento.valor}}</p>
    </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

And the models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    saldo = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Lancamento(models.Model):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey('Tipo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome_usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    valor = models.FloatField()
    descricao = models.TextField()
    data_lancamento = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-data_lancamento']


class Tipo(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

And the views.py, using the Class Based Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from core.models import Lancamento

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'core/index.html')

class LancamentoList(ListView):
    model = Lancamento
    queryset = Lancamento.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, makes more sense now.
Try this out in the template:

```
{% if lancamento.tipo|stringformat:"s" == 'Receita' %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in the project this name are correct 'lancamento_list.html', i put a wrong name in the post here in the stackoverflow. The problem is in {% if lancamento.tipo == 'Receita' %} return false but in the <h4> shows 'Receita' and I dont know why, I need to check this condition to custommize the h4.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hopefully it works for you

Comment: Now are working! Thanks for the help, u can explain me why not working before?